# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] while looping through request

Tags: node.js, express

I'm building a web scraping api for getting back all the working links from a page. I'm keep getting 'Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client' when i try to use res.send - for sending the results - which are a simple text of all the working links...i guess i'm doing something wrong with the way res.send is working....

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var request = require('request');
    var cheerio = require('cheerio');
    var url = 'https://www.pardes-hanna-karkur.muni.il/';

    app.get('/webscrape', function (req, res,next) {
    
    request(url, function(error, response, body){

      if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
            $ = cheerio.load(body);
          links = $('a'); //jquery get all hyperlinks
      $(links).each(function(i, link){
        var linkRecieved = $(link).attr('href');
        if (linkRecieved.indexOf('www') > -1){
          var outStr='';
          request(linkRecieved, function(error, response, body){
            if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
              res.send(linkRecieved);
              next();
              
            } else {
              res.send('false');
              next();
            }
          });
          
        }
        
      });

      }
      
    });

    })

    var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
      var host = server.address().address
      var port = server.address().port
      
      console.log( port)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you only can send response once for a request, on your code it'll try to send response everytime loop execute without an error, try sending response from outside loop

Comment: thanks, i've tried to create a emapy array at the begining of the get request - to collect all the responses...and at the end of the get request  to send it...but it didn't return nothing